# Error GET - Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Tengo un proyecto en react JS el cual consume una API, pero me tira el error del titulo al hacer GET.
Aquí mi código

Articulos.js

```html
import axios from 'axios';

//constants
const dataInicial={
    array:[]
}
const urlArticulos = 'https://mysite.mx/api/articulos';

const GET_ListArticulos_Success='GET_ListArticulos_Success';

//reducer
export default function articulosReducer(state =dataInicial, action){
    switch(action.type){

        case GET_ListArticulos_Success:
        return {...state, array: action.payload};

        default:
            return state
    }
}

//actions
export const getListArticulosAction = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios
    .get(urlArticulos)
    .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
            type:GET_ListArticulos_Success,
            payload:res.data
        })       
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Inventario.js

```html
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import articulosReducer from './Articulos'
 
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    articulos: articulosReducer
})
 
export default function generateStore() {
    const inventario = createStore( rootReducer, composeWithDevTools( applyMiddleware(thunk) ) )
    return inventario
}
```

Routes.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

/* inventario */
import Movimientos from '../pages/Inventario/Movimientos.jsx'

import generateStore from '../redux/inventario';

function Routes() 
{  

const inventario=generateStore();

  return (
    <Router>  
      <Switch>      

        {/* inventario */}
        <Provider store={inventario}>
        <Route exact path="/movimientosInventario">         
            <Movimientos />        
        </Route>
        </Provider>
        
     </Switch>
    </Router>
  );   
  }

export default Routes;
```

Movimientos.jsx

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getListArticulosAction } from '../../redux/Articulos';

const Movimientos = () => {
 const articulos = useSelector(inventario => inventario.articulos.array);

  useEffect(() => { 
    dispatch(getListArticulosAction())
  }, []);    
  

return(
 <>
 </>
 );
};
export default Movimientos;
```